# Check ServerTrustEvaluationFailed is caused by expired certificate

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm using Alamofire 5 and `PinnedCertificatesTrustEvaluator` to avoid MITM attacks. I want to distinguish between an untrusted certificate (MITM attack, server can't be trusted) and an error because the certificate used for pinning is expired.

I might be wrong but I believe in both scenarios Alamofire would return `AFError.serverTrustEvaluationFailed` with reason `certificatePinningFailed`. How can I differentiate between both? On one hand, I'm in a MITM whereas on the other hand the user has an old App version and needs to update (would like to give him feedback about it as they wouldn't be able to keep using the App)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, there are various reasons it can fail. In the expiration case you're likely to see the `.defaultEvaluationFailed` reason, as expiration should be covered under that check rather than the pinning failure. I encourage you test and verify the behavior.

If you need even more detail you can write your own [`ServerTrustEvaluating`](https://alamofire.github.io/Alamofire/Protocols/ServerTrustEvaluating.html#/s:9Alamofire21ServerTrustEvaluatingP8evaluate_7forHostySo03SecC3Refa_SStKF) type that attempts to check properties more specific. Be very careful and write a lot of tests, as that's not something you want to get wrong.